# Change app icon without update

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to change an app logo (on the home screen) without updating the app?

This is from the view of an iOS developer. I got the idea from seeing how the New Yorker newspaper can change their app image without updating the app. Can I do this for a normal app? Is this solely for newstand apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct in that this is solely a newsstand feature for the reason being that content within those applications will change regularly (without requiring a change in the architecture of the application) and provides another way to notify or entice the user to open it again.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, this is only available to Newsstand apps.